# VB.NET Placeholder in MaskedTextBox

Tags: vb.net, placeholder, maskedtextbox

I have a maskedtextbox with the following mask : 999999. I would like to add something like a **placeholder** in HTML to help the end user to know the mask of my maskedtextbox.

I think that i can create a specific mask when the form load and set the text property to "YYYYMM" (the placeholder that i need) and when the user enter in the control, reset the text and change the mask to 999999. However, i think there are better solutions.

I find some people talking about watermark control, but i would like to find something easier to use.

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Have you thought of using a DateTimePicker control?  It can be made to look like a text box and will take custom formats.

Comment: Didn't think about that control. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by tinstaafl in comments, i used a DateTimePicker instead of a MaskedTextBox.

I changed its properties :

```
CustomFormat = yyyMM
Format = Custom
ShowUpDown = True
```

This way, i have something similar to a textBox and i can select only the year or only the month and increase it with the up and down buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DateTimePicker`, that would be the easiest way, as suggested.

However, to do as the question asked...

On `Form_Load`, set `MaskedTextBox1.Text = "YYYYMM"`

Then, to get the effect of changing the mask to 999999 when the control is in focus, use the `MaskedTextBox1_GotFocus` method and use `MaskedTextBox1.Text = "999999"`.

Comment: I already did this on my own. However, i can select days, but i would like to show only months and turn right or left to change year.

Comment: Can you post a picture in the question of your `MaskedTextBox`?

Comment: I will try to only use DateTimePicker control now. Currently, i have this code : DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom  and 
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyyMM"

Comment: @nbadaud Also please be aware that you can set the properties and format without having to physically code them, by using the 'Properties' window. (Select the control, press F4).